# EFcore add data to db from controller

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Hi i want to add data with model directly from my controller without implementing any other.

```
namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{

    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
        readonly HumanDBContext _humanContext;
```

... i want to be able to get data from db  here directly:

```
   [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Godaddy()
        {
```

--fix is here:

```
   public class ApiController : Controller
    {        private readonly HumanDBContext _db;
```

and

```
 public ApiController(IUserService userService,HumanDBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

Comment: humandbcontext retunr null and gets crash

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
public jsonResult Get()
{
  DbCommand cmd = _humanContext.DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()
 cmd.CommandText = "yourspName";
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


using (IDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
 List<Foo> items= reader.Select(r => r.GetYourPocoClassModel()).ToList();

string rItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented,
   new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
 return rItems;
 }
}
```

and GetYourPocoClassModel for modeling your data:

```
public Calss HelperExtension
{
   public static Foo GetYourPocoClassModel(this IDataReader r)
   {
    return new Foo
    {
      Id=r["Id"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(r["Id"]),
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: its done with     public class ApiController : Controller
    {        private readonly HumanDBContext _db;